# Javascript cancel POST from another piece of code using one single function

Tags: javascript

Ok, in my code I have for example, this:

```
$('.follow').click(function(){
        var myself = $(this);
        var data = {
            id: this.getAttribute('data-id')
        }
        $.post('/users/setFriend', data, function(msg){
            myself.text(msg);
            myself.attr('data-status-friends', (myself.attr('data-status-friends').toLowerCase() == 'follow') ? 'following' : 'follow');
        });
    })
```

However, i put a class of 'auth' on certain elements that if the user is logged out, run this bit of JS:

```
$('.auth').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('not logged in');
});
```

This works for the majority of elements, but with the above POST, it seems to still action the POST. How can I definitively cancel the events fired by other bits of code if .auth is clicked?

Comment: `e.stopPropagation()` does the job.

Comment: @idiqual unfortunately this did not work :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think we should talk about propagation or defaultAction preventing here. The point is that you create two *different* series of event handlers: one attached to the `.follow` elements, another - to the `.auth` elements. Of course, if an element has two classes, clicking it will trigger *both* handlers automatically - and they both will be attached to this element (hence no propagation).

The most simple solution here, I think, is to remove `click` handler from an element when you assign `.auth` class to it.

Or, alternatively, you can check `$(this).hasClass('auth')` condition within the `.follow` handler function - and `return false` immediately if that's the case.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than stopping the events, I think a better approach would be either to simply not put events into elements which aren't supposed to be doable without logging in, or track the auth state in your JS code with a variable and check that before doing actions. The latter would probably be a better approach to use if you are building a client-side MVC style application.

Answer (score 0):

You could have two issues going on here with different sets of solutions.

- The listeners are attached to different elements in reverse of what they should be
- The listeners are being attached to the same element

**Different Elements**

Your handlers are out of order, swap them so that e.stopPropogation() is on the inner(child) element and the $.post() call is on the outter(parent) element.

**Same Element**

If the listeners are on the same element, neither e.stopPropogation() nor e.preventDefault() will do what you wish as the event listeners will still fire on the same element.

[stopPropogation()](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/)

> Description: Prevents the event from bubbling up the DOM tree,
>   preventing any parent handlers from being notified of the event.

Propagation according to the [DOM Level 2 Spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html) will still execute all listeners on the same element but not events attached to the parent:

> If the capturing EventListener wishes to prevent further processing of
>   the event from occurring it may call the stopProgagation method of the
>   Event interface. This will prevent further dispatch of the event,
>   although additional EventListeners registered at the same hierarchy
>   level will still receive the event.

[preventDefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/)

> Description: If this method is called, the default action of the event
>   will not be triggered.

Default actions are are based on which element is being acted upon ([W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-DOM-Level-3-Events-20120614/#event-flow-default-cancel)). For a link this would be the redirect to the href="" value, input element to focus it, etc. This is not what you desire as you are most likely not the 'default behavior'.

One option is to attach the handler that calls $.post to an element that is higher on the DOM.

```
$('.follow').parent().click(function(e){e.stopPropogation()})
```

You might have to alter your target HTML so that you have an inner(child) and outter(parent) element to attach your events to. The goal being to have the $.post handler as the outer(parent) and the inner(child) handler cancel the event.

Another option is to add a check to see if the other class is present on your element.

```
$('.follow').click(function(){
    var myself = $(this);

    if(!$(this).hasClass('.auth')){
        var data = {
            id: this.getAttribute('data-id')
        }
        $.post('/users/setFriend', data, function(msg){
            myself.text(msg);
            myself.attr('data-status-friends', (myself.attr('data-status-    friends').toLowerCase() == 'follow') ? 'following' : 'follow');
        });
    }
});
```